# Multiprocessing synchronization between multiple processes (Python)

Tags: python, synchronization, multiprocessing, semaphore

So there in college practical class was an exercise:

> "Create program that defines shared value as 0, then creates and
>   starts 500 processes, each of which increases value of
>   shared value by 1, and finally in the end prints shared value. Run
>   this code few times and see what happens, explain...."

Final version looks like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value


n=Value('i', 0)

def fun():
        n.value+=1

for i in range(500):
        p=Process(target=fun).start()

print n.value
```

Output value varies in range 420-480 and i understand why.

The questions is how to make it always 500 if it possible?
I've been reading Python docs and have found possible solution - Semaphore, but maybe I didn't understand it well..

In the case of Semaphore code looks:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Semaphore

n=Value('i', 0)
sem=Semaphore()

def fun():
        sem.acquire()
        n.value+=1
        sem.release()

for i in range(500):
    p=Process(target=fun).start()
print n.value
```

In this case the final output varies in range 492-495 - way better.

P.S. Do not advise me to use threads from threading class - question is about multiprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processes are not joined. Your lock therefore works, but the value of n is displayed before all of the processes are done to increment it, hence n<500.
You can try the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Semaphore

n=Value('i', 0)
sem=Semaphore()

def fun():
        sem.acquire()
        n.value+=1
        sem.release()

pcs=[]
for i in range(500):
    p=Process(target=fun)
    pcs.append(p)
    p.start()
for i in pcs:
    i.join()
print n.value
```

Comment: Your code works like a first version, and if i define Lock outside loop, before defining functions, it works just like semaphore, because semaphore is a modified lock

Comment: Hey, my bad, the issue seems to actually be that the processes are not being joined, please check out the edited code, I ran it and it seems to work fine. The semaphore you setup works well.

Comment: In your edited code is no sense for me.. What i want is to execute all processes parallel, and if i join every process after it start it just works like normal loop 'for i in range(500)' - every process will not start before previous didn't end, and you do not need any semaphore or lock for this. For example if you put time.sleep(1) inside function - you will need to wait 500 seconds till it end.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I got the indentation wrong. Basically, put the join outside the loop. Now all processes are started, and joined before the value is printed. The original issue was that it did not wait for every processes to be finished in order to print the output, it just waited for it to be started. The last few processes would not be finished before printing the output. Adding "p.join()" allows to wait for all processes to be finished before printing it.

Comment: will try it tomorrow, ty btw!

Comment: TY, it works! Just a small fix from me - to put all created processes in array and join them all at once